# Opening a React App through a HTML file's <a href> link

Tags: html, reactjs, href

I have a HTML file with a list of links.
Some of the links lead to other HTML files, but I want one to lead to a react application.
I have not been able to open the app like I would a normal HTML though. Not through public/index.html or src/App.js.

How do I open a React application through a simple link?

Here is an example of the link list in the current HTML:

```
<a href="snake/game.html">Snake</a>
<a href="snake/game.html">Snake</a>
<a href="myApp/src/App.js">React App</a> <!--problem on this line-->
```

Comment: See if this helps: [Add React to a Website](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html).  Assumptions: 1) you've successfully hosted your React app on the web site, and 2) the procedure that the article describes matches what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the link of server of react that you have started using `npm start` .
It's `http://localhost:5000` by default.
So write

```
<a href="http://localhost:5000">React App</a> <!--problem solved-->
```

But make sure you have started react app on server by `npm start`